# Auth login using express mysql to an existing wp accounts

Tags: express, react-router, express-session

im building a login pwa with react and node for a existing wp site, how can i check the pass provide by user when signin with the encrypt wp password generate when the user created the account through wp? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

WordPress makes use of md5 encryption so if you can use the below package to encrypt the entered password and check for the user authentication.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5

```
var md5 = require('md5');
if(password == md5('secret')){
  //true
}
else 
{
  //wrong password
}
```